# How to select childs from a superclass?

Tags: java, sql

I have a basic JPA mapping with a superclass containing a list.

How can I select all List row entries from the database for a specific person?

```
class Person {
    @Id
    int id;

    @OneToMany
    List<Payment> payments;
}

//SELECT <all payments> from Person p WHERE p.id = 1
```

Comment: Why don't you `SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id=1` and get the payments?

Comment: Because it's just an example and I'd like to know how to only get the "list" entries directly. Eventually I will make deeper filter inside the payments (eg filter all records that are above a certain amount. I'd like to do this also on DB level, not after fetching the whole entity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do `SELECT person.payments FROM Person person JOIN person.payments WHERE person.id = ?`.

You would cast the return `list()` to a `List<Payment>`